# Prove or disprove that If $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$, then $ab \mid c$.

Tags: divisibility

So I am not really sure what to do. I know by the definition of divisibility there must exist some integers $k$ and $l$ such that

$$
c= ak \  \text{  and  } \ c=bl
$$

But now I am stuck and have no clue where to go from here...

I need to show that $c=ab(\text{some integer})$, for it to be divisible, but I do not see the path to take.

Comment: Think about prime factors, as you always should when you have divisibility.  Suppose all the numbers are powers of the same prime.  What happens?

Comment: With a statement like this, it's often best to look for a counterexample before you start trying to prove that it is true. Can you think of an integer that is divisible by two integers but not by their product?

Comment: What two positive integers do you *know* divide $c$?  What if $a$ and $b$ are both the larger of those two numbers?

Comment: if a=2, and b=8, and c=8, then we have that a|c, and b|c, but ab does not divide c. So then this would be a disprove type question?

Comment: What do you mean by prime factors?

Comment: yes exactly that's a good counterexample (or simply $a=b=c=2$)

Comment: oh okay, I must have been overthinking it. Thank you for all of your guy's help!!

Comment: yeah that a=b=c=2 makes sense too. Because ab will be bigger than c which would not yield in an integer. Makes total sense now.

Comment: I feel really silly now for not getting it right away. Thank you everyone again.

Answer (score 1):

If $a= b = c > 1$ then
$a|c, b|c, ab \not\mid c$.